# How to delete the draft version of an app on AGC?

Tags: appgallery-connect

After a new version was submitted for review, due to incorrect operation, another version was created, which looks like a closed beta version. This version is currently in draft status and has not been submitted for review.

How can I delete the draft version of an app on AGC?

[image: Remove_draft_version]

Comment: It is called Huawei App Gallery Connect. Please use services name for people to understand what is this question about.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: There's still no way to do it that I can see. It's quite annoying.

Answer (score 0):

The daft version cannot be deleted. If you want to make any change to the draft version, you can go and make the change directly before submitting it for further review.

[image]